# JDeveloper 10g error not highlighting

Tags: jdeveloper

I have recently shifted to work on Jdeveloper ide version 10.1.3 for one of our project, the ide doesn't assists me when I make any kind of errors in the code like eclipse and other ide's highlights, at the time of complying the project the errors are shown on the console window, I have tried with different ways but no solution.

I have checked in windows menu it don't have an option for rest factory settings, I have searched that option in tools menu too but there is no such option, please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking to the JDeveloper ide options one by one, the reset factory settings available in tools->preferences->audit->profiles. Now JDeveloper highlights me the syntax errors, this may be helpful to someone who is very new to this ide. Once reset factory settings done restart ide.